# Every 1. day in month I need to update my custom number field with default value "2"

Tags: workflow, formula, field-update, time-dependent-workflow

I don´t know how to do it via workflow with update field, because something must activate my workflow... It must be:
Created 
or 
created, and every time it’s edited 
or
created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria.

So how to trigger(start) my workflow(field update) every 1.day in month( for ex. 1.5.2015 00:01)
?

Thanks to all for your proposals

BTW:  I NEED TO THIS WITHOUT CODE.. SO NO APEX PLEASE.Only with standart functionalities

Comment: I suggest you to read https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas first. The key is 'calculated at run-time'.

Comment: @Lukas: Do you mean: custom field or formula field? What is your goal? What field should have a different value of the first of the month and what should be the difference?
Triggering workflows by date only will be very difficult, maybe a formula that displays different values depending on the month will be better.

Comment: Chiz - Many thanks.. this kind of help you proposed why? Do you think that I can not read? This is standart help from users like you, which don´t know how to help.

Comment: Sorry, I mean custom field.. I have some custom field and every month (1.5.2015 00:01) I need to set default value for ex. "2".

Answer (score 1):

You can use Time Based Workflow with entry criteria except created and every time it’s edited as time based actions does not support this entry criteria.
Also refer link for better understanding:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245

Comment: I cannot use Time Based Workflow. If you would like propose this solution, plese propose example... not only unspecific help like others